Problems uploading and downloading files after upgrade
After running, sudo apt-get upgrade -y, I can neither upload nor download files.
Current: 24.04.01 LTS
When uploading, I get the error message that permission denied. When downloading, Firefox hangs and has to be closed.
This is very annoying for me right now.
All the pictures from my Myanmar research trip are on the PC. So I can't reinstall it.
At the same time, I can't print my bank statements as a PDF, which would be necessary for applying for Social Security benefits.
System:
 Kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
 Desktop: GNOME v: 46.0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
 Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20C6S09W00 v: ThinkPad Edge E540
   serial: <filter>
 Mobo: LENOVO model: 20C6S09W00 v: 0B98401 WIN serial: <filter>
   UEFI-[Legacy]: LENOVO v: J9ET9DWW (2.23 ) date: 02/04/2016
Battery:
 ID-1: BAT0 charge: 18.1 Wh (98.4%) condition: 18.4/56.2 Wh (32.7%)
CPU:
 Info: quad core model: Intel Core i7-4712MQ bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache:
   L2: 1024 KiB
 Speed (MHz): avg: 2376 min/max: 800/3300 cores: 1: 800 2: 2914 3: 2836
   4: 800 5: 3300 6: 2100 7: 2960 8: 3300
Graphics:
 Device-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics driver: i915
   v: kernel
 Device-2: Bison Integrated Camera driver: uvcvideo type: USB
 Display: server: X.Org v: 23.2.6 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
   loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: crocus gpu: i915
   resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
 API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: crocus,swrast platforms: x11,surfaceless,device
 API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.2
   renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
 API: Vulkan v: 1.3.296 drivers: N/A surfaces: xcb,xlib
Audio:
 Device-1: Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio
   driver: snd_hda_intel
 Device-2: Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio
   driver: snd_hda_intel
 API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-48-generic status: kernel-api
Network:
 Device-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8211/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
   driver: r8169
 IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
 Device-2: Intel Wireless 7260 driver: iwlwifi
 IF: wlp4s0 state: up mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
 Device-1: Intel Bluetooth wireless interface driver: btusb type: USB
 Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 4.0
Drives:
 Local Storage: total: 232.89 GiB used: 174.37 GiB (74.9%)
 ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 850 EVO 250GB size: 232.89 GiB
Partition:
 ID-1: / size: 228.17 GiB used: 174.37 GiB (76.4%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
Swap:
 ID-1: swap-1 type: file size: 4 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) file: /swap.img
Sensors:
 System Temperatures: cpu: 56.0 C mobo: N/A
 Fan Speeds (rpm): cpu: 0 fan-2: 0
Info:
 Memory: total: 8 GiB available: 7.47 GiB used: 3.05 GiB (40.8%) igpu: 32 MiB
 Processes: 284 Uptime: 2h 57m Shell: Sudo inxi: 3.3.34


The error has only now occurred completely independently of BIOS settings. Assuming that does not apply, the update or upgrade has problems with these settings.
download: For example, a notice of termination from the Federal Employment Agency homepage into the download folder. Upload: For example, a screen screenshot on Twitter

/home/aporie/Bilder/Bildschirmfotos
/home/aporie/Downloads


Not sure what you are describing. Those problems - are they firefox related? "Upload" and "download" refer to operations done with firefox?

Yes, Firefox hangs during the download and must be closed.
When uploading, there is an error message that access is denied.
Under Opera, downloads are blocked or load with 0 bytes and a question mark.

Since firefox is delivered as snap try to install either a snapless firefox or some other browser as .deb file. I assume that snap and not firefox is the culprit

This question is similar to: How to install Firefox as a traditional deb package (without snap) in Ubuntu 22.04 or later versions?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
